# How to remove "\n" in a list of lists (python)

Tags: python, list, file, newline

I have a giant list of lists that I imported from a file like this:

```
letters = []
for i in range(len(string)):
    let = []
    for j in range(7):
        line = infile.readline()
        let = let + [line]
    letters.append(let)
    infile.readline()
```

Its a big list of lists, but each secondary list has a \n at the end of it.

```
[['   ###   \n', '  ## ##  \n', ' ##   ## \n', '##     ##\n', 
'#########\n', '##     ##\n', '##     ##\n'], ['######## \n',
'##     ##\n', '##     ##\n', '######## \n', '##     ##\n',
'##     ##\n', '######## \n'], ... ]]
```

How do I remove the \n? so its just

```
[['   ###   ', '  ## ##  ', ' ##   ## ', '##     ##', 
'#########', '##     ##', '##     ##'], ['######## ',
'##     ##', '##     ##', '######## ', '##     ##',
'##     ##', '######## '], ... ]]
```

It's important to have the spaces in there as well. I've tried doing

```
 letters.strip("\n")
```

but that didnt work.

Please help!

EDIT: I think it might be a problem with the

```
line = infile.readline()
```

but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My desired output is

```
    ###    #######  ########
```

but instead i'm getting this

```
    ###
  #######
 ########
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: How about `letters = [letter.strip() for letter in letters]`? You can't just call `strip` (a **string** method) on the whole list at once!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using python 3 in IDLE. When I tried the .strip("\n") it gave me this error.

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You have a list of lists. The `strip` method operates on strings, not lists.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought @AlexReynolds when posting my answer, would it work? OP doesn't have a minimal example...

Answer (score 3):

Wherever your current code has a call to `.readline()`, make it `.readline().rstrip('\n')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
line = infile.readline()
line = line.strip('\n')
let = let + [line]
```

Comment: Strings don't get modified in-place in standard Python.  Your output of .strip() is not being used.

Comment: Yes, said jez, and then padded his comment to reach the minimum length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `\n` from the last element only, use this:

```
t[-1] = t[-1].strip()
```

If you want to remove `\n` from all the elements, use this:

```
t = map(lambda s: s.strip(), t)
```

You might also consider removing `\n` before splitting the line:

```
line = line.strip()
```

Comment: Why not use [**`string.strip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) instead of defining the `lambda`?