# How do I split the values and convert to float in a list if they are all in a single quotation?

Tags: python, string, text

I have a list that contents are:

```
a=['0.00244,-0.001908302,-0.001731396,0.002029896,0.000424,0.000291,0.000148\n']
```

So it contains one member that has numbers in it.

I tried to search for different methods to extract the numbers in float format, as in:

*[How to remove '\n' from end of strings inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325212/how-to-remove-n-from-end-of-strings-inside-a-list)*

*[Remove '\n' from each string stored in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488579/remove-n-from-each-string-stored-in-a-python-list)*

*[How to remove "\n" in a list of lists (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990675/how-to-remove-n-in-a-list-of-lists-python)*

*[How to remove '\n' from end of strings inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325212/how-to-remove-n-from-end-of-strings-inside-a-list)*

But their difference with my case is that all of my numbers are inside one `''`, so once I use

```
 a=[a[0].strip('\n')]
```

then the

```
a[0].split()
```

this gives me:

```
['0.00244,-0.001908302,-0.001731396,0.002029896,0.000424,0.000291,0.000148']
```

I can remove the `\n`, but then I can not extract the numbers in any way. I wanted to split the commas away from the numbers to then remove them one by one, but it seems that split is not working in my case.

Comment: maybe specify the delimiter ","? `a[0].split(",")`

Comment: use a=a[0].split(",") instead of a[0].split() it will give you the proper output you are expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lgwilliams mentioned in the comments. You need to specify a delimiter in `split` otherwise it will default to `' '`. In this case you would use `split(',')`. You then need to convert these numbers by casting to `float` which will, as mhawke mentioned, remove the `\n`.

With all this in mind you can perform a list comprehension

```
In [17]: a = ['0.00244,-0.001908302,-0.001731396,0.002029896,0.000424,0.000291,0.000148\n']

In [18]: numbers = [float(n) for n in a[0].split(',')]

In [19]: numbers
Out[19]:
[0.00244,
 -0.001908302,
 -0.001731396,
 0.002029896,
 0.000424,
 0.000291,
 0.000148]
```

You could also use `map`

```
In [22]: list(map(float, a[0].split(',')))
Out[22]:
[0.00244,
 -0.001908302,
 -0.001731396,
 0.002029896,
 0.000424,
 0.000291,
 0.000148]
```

Comment: Minor point: stripping the new line is not necessary, `float()` will ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using regular expression to extract the float values from string and convert to float

```
list(map(float,re.findall(r'(\-?\d+.\d+)',a[0])))
```

Out:

```
[0.00244,
 -0.001908302,
 -0.001731396,
 0.002029896,
 0.000424,
 0.000291,
 0.000148]
```

Comment: thank you , it worked but not when all the values were 0

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be to split on the commas:

```
'0.00244,-0.001908302,-0.001731396,0.002029896,0.000424,0.000291,0.000148'.split(',')
```

Would result in:

```
['0.00244', '-0.001908302', '-0.001731396', '0.002029896', '0.000424', '0.000291', '0.000148']
```